# Online dependence not found in .ivy2 file and not found by Intellij Idea

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt, ivy

I have an IntelliJ Idea project that uses external libraries. I cannot find one of this libraries in the `~/.ivy2/cache` directory. The sbt file looks like:

```
name := "myproject"
scalaVersion := "2.11.8"
lazy val toImport = RootProject(uri("someuri#hash"))
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).dependsOn(toImport)
```

IntelliJ Idea underlines the `toImport` line saying that it cannot find it. How can I solve this?

Comment: Have you tried updating from command line? "sbt update; sbt updateClassifiers; sbt updateSbtClassifiers"

Comment: @motilio yes i tried but nothing happens im trying to compile the source and use the jar but sbt package does not work

Comment: look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9441441/how-to-set-up-an-intellij-idea-scala-project-to-recognize-local-ivy2-cache?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean the `RootProject` is highlighted red, it seem you've run into a problem with how IDEA imports transitive modules. I've reproduced this with the information from your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45471836/problems-with-sbt-dependencies-in-intellij-idea#45471836) and created an issue on the Scala plugin issue tracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-12355

To work around this problem, one "fix" is to manually rename the modules in project structure to this:

[image]

... but that will get lost after refreshing the project from sbt.

Instead, I suggest you enable the "use sbt for build and import" in the sbt options. You will have the highlighting error, but builds will work fine.