# NoClassDefFoundError using sbt for builds and imports in Intellij Idea

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I have described in several [SO questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45471836/problems-with-sbt-dependencies-in-intellij-idea) a problem I experienced while trying to work with the following project dependency structure combining Intellij Idea and sbt:

[image]

The ultimate goal is to be able to debug my proofs in all the levels of the stack. The program now builds by enabling the "use sbt for build and import" option in the Intellij Idea settings.

However, I'm getting the following run-time error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: inox/ast/Types$Type
    at Main$.main(Main.scala:9)
    at Main.main(Main.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: inox.ast.Types$Type
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 2 more
```

Here Main is the Main object in the proof I'm writing (so on top of the stack).

Why does this happen? How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem was solved by adding the dependency from my project to Inox module manually in the Project Structure window. You may find the whole process documented [here](https://github.com/rjraya/vec/blob/master/debugging.pdf).