# Debugging a software verifier written in sbt on Intellij Idea

Tags: scala, debugging, intellij-idea, sbt, formal-verification

I'm working with [Stainless](https://github.com/epfl-lara/stainless), a software verifier for Scala programs. I would like to debug the verification process of a sample programme on Intellij Idea. On a previous post, I solved this integration problem for an [interactive theorem prover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45471836/problems-with-sbt-). But now, I'm facing two problems:

1. Apparently, the verification software runs at compile time. That is, I enter in the sbt console and run the compile command and then the verification process seems to be done. You may try this with this [verified example](https://github.com/epfl-lara/verified-2048). This situation is new to me, since I was used to debug the program while executing.
2. All the setup in the sbt files of the example above (see for instance [this file](https://github.com/epfl-lara/verified-2048/blob/master/project/plugins.sbt)) seem to refer to online content, while I want to make sure that I work with my local copy forked from the original repository of the verifier.

None of the configurations I tried worked. Can you help me out of this problem?

**Details**

[This](https://github.com/rjraya/stainless/blob/master/core/src/sphinx/installation.rst#id1) is the current configuration page of stainless.

Comment: note that sbt version should be 0.13. not 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the verification runs within the sbt process, you can debug it by attaching the debugger to sbt. IntelliJ makes this easy with the embedded sbt shell:

[image: enable sbt shell debugging]

1. open the sbt shell toolwindow
2. click the "attach debugger to sbt shell" button on the left
3. set breakpoints in your code
4. run the task

Comment: Did you test this with the actual library? I did the steps you pointed but is not really working. In particular:

using the plugin i think im not setting breakpoint in the right place (don't know where the source of the plugging is)

if I use the script generated after compilation with sbt which is stainless-scalac file it gives the error:

...
[error] Not a valid key: stainless-scalac (similar: stainlessVersion)
[error] stainless-scalac ./src/main/scala/*.scala
[error]                 ^