# Debugging a software verifier written in Scala working as plugin of sbt

Tags: scala, debugging, sbt, verification

I'm working with [Stainless](https://github.com/epfl-lara/stainless), a software verifier for Scala programs. I would like to debug the verification process of a sample programme. On a previous post, I solved this integration problem for an [interactive theorem prover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45471836/problems-with-sbt-). But now, I'm facing two problems:

Apparently, the verification software runs at compile time. That is, I enter in the sbt console and run the compile command and then the verification process seems to be done. You may try this with this [verified example](https://github.com/epfl-lara/verified-2048). This situation is new to me, since I was used to debug the program while executing.

Alternatively, I found out that it [was possible](https://daodecode.com/2013/04/19/debug-an-sbt-plugin-in-intellij-idea/) (2013) to debug plugins in Intellij Idea and this may be the case with the [released](https://github.com/epfl-lara/stainless/blob/master/core/src/sphinx/installation.rst) (see section on sbt) plugin for using Stainless on Sbt.

So to clarify , I'm looking for a complete set up that would allow me to debug the verification process from the terminal/with some specific software in a way that I can follow the control flow/variables etc, of Stainless and my own project.

**Details**

[This](https://github.com/rjraya/stainless/blob/master/core/src/sphinx/installation.rst#id1) is the current configuration page of stainless.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51211552/debugging-a-software-verifier-written-in-sbt-on-intellij-idea) is my question on how to solve this problem on Intellij Idea (more challenging I guess)

**Pipeline**

In case it helps I leave the pipeline of the tool posted here (took it from documentation):

[image]

**Additional observations**

There is an open issue for this in [Intellij Idea](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-14081) support.

An alternative I have to experiment with is the Scala REPL.

Answer (score 2):

I'm looking for this tools too but I don't found any good. I try logger and there're fine for me.

[scala-logger: Simple Scala friendly logging interface.](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwio1ayuxaHcAhVmUd8KHVqPDVcQFggpMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Flightbend%2Fscala-logging&usg=AOvVaw0cnYxtwaaGaO7rkdnUlYiA)

[Logback Project for backend](https://logback.qos.ch)

Comment: this is good as an idea, but i would still need some elaboration. how is this tool supposed to work, how it applies to my problem, in particular note the comment to the bounty (in yellow above)

Comment: following my comment above, a complete procedure of debugging of my project would be very helpful to me

Comment: after having looked at it, i think this is not the tool that Im looking for, since the code already has logging inserted, i can also println whathever interests me, the problem is having a complete debug information

Comment: yes, println is very useful. Debug information, like what? variables? Threads? or what?
also you can take a look to https://index.scala-lang.org/johnreedlol/scala-trace-debug/scala-trace-debug/4.5.0?target=_2.11
maybe help you.

Comment: I'm thinking on the ability to follow the control-flow of the program, going through the actual code, putting breakpoints where I want to stop, inspect variables there, etc either in terminal or any other environment you may think